# PIL thumbnail GIF distorted colors on LED matrix

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, gif

I have a script that converts GIFs into smaller, 128x32 pixel size using .thumbnail. These GIFs are then displayed on a 128x32 LED matrix.

The problem is, when resized, and displayed on the LED matrix, GIFs with background colors end up looking very noisy, a lot of static, and distortion. However, for GIFs with just black backgrounds, they seem fine. Am I missing something? Perhaps this is a resampling issue?

Examples:

**1. GIF with black background**

[image]
[image]

**2. GIF with colored background**
[image]
[image]

Look how noisy the 2nd GIF is compared to its original GIF.

```
def getUserGIFs(self):

f = open('csv/GIF_settings.json', 'r')
all_settings = json.load(f)
f.close()


for ind,fle in enumerate(all_settings['images']):
            
            try:
                GIF = Image.open(os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'user_uploads'), fle))
                frames = []

                    for i, frame in enumerate(ImageSequence.Iterator(GIF)):
                        
                        frame = frame.convert('P')
                        frame.thumbnail((128, 32),Image.LANCZOS)

                        f = self.stitchImage([frame])
                        frames.append(f)


                frames[0].save('./display_images/working_gif{}.gif'.format(str(ind)), save_all=True, append_images=frames[1:], loop=0, optimize = False)
                GIF = Image.open('./display_images/working_gif{}.gif'.format(str(ind)))
                GIFs.append(GIF)


            except Exception as e:
                logf = open('log.txt', "a")
                exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
                fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
                logf.write(str(e))
                logf.write('. file: ' + fname)
                logf.write('. line: ' +  str(exc_tb.tb_lineno))
                logf.write('. type: ' +  str(exc_type))
                logf.write('\n ' + "".join(traceback.format_exception(sys.exc_info()[0], sys.exc_info()[1], sys.exc_info()[2])))
                logf.close()

        return GIFs
```

Comment: What is the result when the entire image is (constant) solid brown?

Comment: @Rotem Brown seems to be the same, I've tried GIFs with other colored backgrounds and they also have this issue.

Comment: What I have meant is that the **entire image** content is solid brown (not just the background), and that the color is constant (not changes over time). Did you test that?

Comment: @Rotem Just tested it, there were no artifacts or noise. Solid brown color.